# How to apply different gradient on background and text

Tags: html, css

I'm using background color with webkit gradient effect in CSS

```
.show {
  background: rgb(242,242,242);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(242,242,242,1) 0%, rgba(222,222,222,1) 52%, rgba(193,193,193,1) 100%);
  opacity: 0.4;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #E4E9ED;
}
```

This works fine but once I try to add gradient on hover to `.show` class with `<a>` tag to text it fails to work:

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
.navigation-bar .show li a:hover{
  background-color: orange;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: .1s .2s;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #c41316 1%,#e00003, transparent 50%); /*-webkit-linear-gradient(left, hotPink 0%, orange 50%, transparent 50%);*/
  background-position: 100% 0;
  background-size: 200% 200%;
}
}
```

This code works fine on other text, but I think the `.show` gradient background has impact on `.show li a:hover` gradient text.

How can I apply gradient text on gradient background?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/yotking789/pen/vYEeEPV) (Do notice you need to scroll down to see the problem)

Comment: I'm not sure what's your problem but try using `background: rgb(242,242,242) linear-gradient ...` *(in one line)* instead of 2 lines property `background: rgb(242,242,242);
  background: linear-gradient...` because writing 2 lines the previous one might be overridden by the latter.

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh didn't worked, I'm sure something is interrupting the gradient to work in `show` class, but i can't figure out what..

Comment: Honestly I haven't got your question, just give some suggestions anyway.

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh Watch the codepen I've posted, the menu contains gradient text once you hover it, then if you scroll down the gradient text fails to exist. my question is how can I fix that

Comment: You can search for `@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)` in your CSS, that's what affects the appearance of those navs.

Comment: No, when you keep hovering on a menu text while scrolling, the gradient disappears (I'm using chrome 79.0.3945.88). Check my answer below for a quick fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `background-position: 100% 0;` inside

```css
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) .navigation-bar .show li a:hover {...}
```

How did I come to this conclusion?

When you scroll, this one `@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) .navigation-bar .show li a:hover {...}` overrides this one `@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) .navigation-bar li a`.
When you remove the properties from the former bit by bit, it works when `background-position: 100% 0;` is removed.

Comment: what did you understand?